# Return PHP/MySQL results in HTML form for editing

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a database that users can search by any number of predetermined fields (chosen from a drop down).  The problem I'm having is being able to edit existing records.  The first script prompts for the record ID to edit.  If no record is found the user is told to try again.

When a record is found the results are suppose to display in HTML input boxes.  The user can then modify the data, hit submit and the record updates (another script).

Enabled errors.  This is what is thrown:

Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetch__assoc() in (path to script) on line 37

Any ideas on what is wrong?

```html
<?php
    //Include everything but the password to connect to db
    include 'includes/connect_pw.php';

    //User supplies password on previous form
    $dbpass = $_POST['password'];     

    //User supplies id on previous form
    $rec_id = $_POST['query'];

    //Create connection to database using mysqli
    $conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $db);

    //Check connection. If error then kill process, show error and tell user to retry
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die ("<br><br>" . $conn->connect_error . "<p></p>Did you forget the password?");
    }

    //If no error then set select statement as variable 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM dcr_master
            WHERE (`ID` = '".$rec_id."')";
    //Pass select ($sql) into connection ($conn) with result to ($result)
    //Set new variables to populate input boxes.  ex: $variable = $row['record field']
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows >=1) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch__assoc()) {
            $Server_Name = $row['Server_Name'];
            $Description = $row['Description'];
            $IP_Address = $row['IP_Address'];
            $Wiki_Link = $row['Wiki_Link'];

        }
?>
<form action="modify_dcr_3.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="<?=$rec_id;?>">
Server Name<input type="text" name="Server_Name" value="<?=$Server_Name;?>">
Description<input type="text" name="Description" value="<?=$Description;?>">
IP_Address<input type="text" name="IP_Address" value="<?=$IP_Address;?>">
Wiki_Link<input type="text" name="Wiki_Link" value="<?=$Wiki_Link;?>">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<?php
        }
    else    {
        echo "<rb><br>No matching ID found.
              <p></p>Try again. Just don't use " .$rec_id. " OK?";
    }   
?>
```

Comment: completly blank screen could be a syntax error. did you try turning on error reporting?

Comment: Just learned how to enable errors.  Thank you for that!!!              Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetch__assoc() in (path to script) on line 37

Comment: Did it help you in fixing your problem?

Comment: edit your question instead of putting it in the comment

Comment: Edited post as well.  Pardon the Noobishness.  I'm looking at the line in question (if...while...) and haven't a clue.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a double underscore on `fetch__assoc()`, this should have only a single underscore: [`fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php). Specifically change this:

```
    while ($row = $result->fetch__assoc()) {
        ...
    }
```

To:

```
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Excellent catch sir!  Looks like CodeLobster PHP Edition failed to flag that.  Input fields now display current data. Thank you!!